# CMS choice for webservices

Tags: php, web-services, content-management-system

I'm planing to make a website that allows users to register and enter a personal area of the webiste where they can run a webservice.
For this personal area, I would like to have a dashboard structure, similar to wp-admin, but specifically created for the pages that I want to put in that area.
My programming skills are pretty good and I could probably create this from scratch, but I don't have that much time and I've been out of website development fields for years, so I would like to have some suggestion on which CMS I could use to make such a website.
Just to give you an example I would like to have something like kraken.com where users sing up and enter a page with a different template.

So far the only idea I had was to start from wordpress and completely change the admin dashboard hiding all the options to edit pages and posts. I'm not sure if that is a good idea...

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial **or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: Apologies for posting a question that is off-topic for SO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

most of CMSs can do this but i think drupal have a good management on acl & webservices